# Python with statement issue

Tags: python

New to python and found one box still running very old code that doesn't support the with statement and admins not interested in upgrading as it will be replaced, but no ETA on replacement and need to get my script working

On another box with later version script works fine, but need to get it working on this older box

Extract from working script on later version

```
with open("ping.log","r") as reader:
    while True:
        line = reader.readline()
        if len(line)==0:
            break

        status = line[34]
        name = line[16:30]
        if (status=="d"):
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="red">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td>\n</tr>\n'
        else:
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="green">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td></tr>\n'
```

It basically opens file reads the contents and looks at specific position to see if device is up or down and make it red or green

Now I know you can use something like

```
fileh = open(file, 'w')
try:
    # Do things with fileh here  
finally:
    fileh.close()
```

Need help with the part between try and finally

Comment: I believe you've changed all of the things that need to be changed, actually. The rest should be the same, except that you called your variable `file` and the original code called it `reader`.

Comment: Apologies, that was copy paste error, I tried this code

fileh = open("ping.log","r") as reader:
try:
    while True:
        if len(line)==0:
            break

        status = line[34]
        name = line[16:30]
        if (status=="d"):
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="red">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td>\n</tr>\n'
        else:
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="green">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td></tr>\n'
finally:
        fileh.close()

but from the start get error on the as reader part

Answer (score 0):

You were actually on the right path:

```py
fileh = open("ping.log", 'r') # you don't need the as reader part
try:
    for line in fileh:            # you can just iterate over the file, no need for while True
        if len(line)==0:
            break
        status = line[34]
        name = line[16:30]
        if (status == "d"):
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="red">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td>\n</tr>\n'
        else:
            html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="green">'+ name+'</font><br>\n</td></tr>\n'
except:
    print("ERROR")
finally:
    fileh.close()
```

You could even make a variable color and set it depending on your status, so the lines are easier to change later like:

```py
...
    color = "red" if (status == "d") else "green"
    html+= '<tr>\n<td>\n<font color="' + color + '">'+ name + '</font><br>\n</td>\n</tr>\n'
...
```

**EDIT**: As suggested, I updated for try, except, finally

**EDIT 2**:
For your second problem, as I understand it, you want to write or append to the file dash.aspx?

Then you wouldn't have to iterate over it

```py
...
writer = open("dash.apsx", "w") #You need to check whether you want to use 'a' or 'w' for appending or writing
#no need to iterate over writerlines, you already have the file and can directly write to it

#INFO: this will put everything on one line, for new lines you could add "\n" e.g. writer.write(htmlBeg + "\n") etc.
writer.write(htmlBeg) 
writer.write("<tr>") 
writer.write(htmlTBeg) 
writer.write('<th style="text-align:left"><h3>APAC Region Firewalls</h3></th>') 
writer.write(html) 
writer.write(htmlTEnd)
#close file at the end
write.close()
...
```

Comment: The `try:` and `finally:` in the OP's original attempt were useful and possibly necessary if this is part of a larger script which loops over files or something. You are not closing the file even in the success scenario so this code has a leak.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm on the right track now, at least got part of the script to run without any errors following guidelines given, will adjust complete script and let you know how it goes, I do include the close after each part of script as indeed as you say due to larger script it causes leaks if not closed

Comment: ok first part of script now working, but now getting traceback error on next part of script when trying to create the HTML file

writehtml = open("dash.aspx","w")
for writer in writehtml:
    writer.write(htmlBeg)
    writer.write("<tr>")

    writer.write(htmlTBeg)
    writer.write('<th style="text-align:left"><h3>APAC Region Firewalls</h3></th>')
    writer.write(html)
    writer.write(htmlTEnd)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dash.py", line 52, in ?
    for writer in writehtml:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: darn formatting issue on my side ignore above comment, script now running without errors thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The `as fileh` part needs to be changed to an assignment to the file handle variable you want to use, `reader`, and that basically fixes it.

To wit,

```py
reader = open("ping.log", 'r')  # not 'w' if you are reading
try:
    # Do things with reader here
    # Basically copy-paste the stuff which was inside the with statement
finally:
    reader.close()
```